# How do I export a simple saved model graph for image classification with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have the following code right now, but it isn't working. I am trying to take in one image for an input and the classifier will output some tags. The training is working with outputting a graph, but I need the saved model for GCP upload.

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.image)
outputs = tf.placeholder(tf.string)

tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess,
        export_dir,
        inputs={"x": inputs},
        outputs={"z": outputs})
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I also have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In case you trained your model with `tf.keras`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# The export path contains the name and the version of the model
tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0) # Ignore dropout at inference
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./model.h5')
export_path = './1'

# Fetch the Keras session and save the model
# The signature definition is defined by the input and output tensors
# And stored with the default serving key
with tf.keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
    tf.saved_model.simple_save(
        sess,
        export_path,
        inputs={'input_image': model.input},
        outputs={t.name:t for t in model.outputs})
```